# Spring boot rest Ajax Post JSON Hashset

Tags: java, ajax, spring

i have entity user. User have role hash set.I have form edit user and i want post from ajax to spring boot rest controller user but i have error :

"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashSet` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashSet` out of START_OBJECT token"

What should I do to get the user to Controller?

Controller

```
@PutMapping("/admin/edit/")
public void editUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    ...
```

Ajax

```
function editUser() {
    var roles = [
        {"name" : $('#role').val()}
    ]
    var user = {
        "id" : $('#id').val(),
        "name" : $('#name').val(),
        "login" : $('#login').val(),
        "password" : $('#password').val(),
        "roles" : roles
    }

    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/api/users",
        datatype: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        success: function(data){
            $(location).attr('href',"/admin");
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert(error);
        }
    }).done()
}
```

`

Comment: Try to analyze the request in Network Tab in developer tools and see what request body you are sending as JSON to the Backend.

Comment: Looks like roles array is not the correct format and User object can't be deserialized